# Only show a user's profile if they are contacts with current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :is_contact, only: [:show]

  def index
    @contacts = User.joins(:groups)
                   .where(groups: {id: current_user.groups})
                   .where.not(id: current_user).uniq
  end

  def show

  end

  private

  def is_contact
    user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if user = !@contacts
      flash[:alert] = "Sorry, you don't know each other."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

My contacts view, where you can either send a message (working) or view profile (not working):

```
 <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
     <h3><%= contact.name %></h3>
     <%= link_to 'view profile', user_path(contact), class: "btn"
  <% end %>
```

Comment: `user = !@contacts` doesn't make any sense, not the least bit because that's an *assignment* with `=` and not a comparison with `==`. Maybe you mean `@contacts.any?` or `@contacts.include?(user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed that `@contacts` is an instance variable and it is not shared across requests. Basically when you try to see if there is contacts in the method `is_contact`, the `@contacts` variable is nil.

Show and index are 2 different requests. When you access the index page `@contacts` variable has been created, but when you click the user link on the index page, then another request to show action is made, and in that request you do not have data that was set for `index` action. You would need to make a db query to get contacts separately for show action.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :contacts, only: %i[index show]
  before_action :is_contact, only: [:show]

  def index; end

  def show; end

  private

  def contacts
    @contacts ||= User.joins(:groups)
                  .where(groups: {id: current_user.groups})
                  .where.not(id: current_user).uniq
  end

  def is_contact
    user = User.find(params[:id)

    unless @contacts.detect { |contact| contact.id == user.id }
      flash[:alert] = "Sorry, you don't know each other."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: and also in your query you do not need to exclude your user id from the users, since you still want to allow the user to view their own profiles :)

Comment: @HarryMattocks I've updated the `is_contact` in my answer, please take a look. I've missed the part that you need to check if user is in your contacts list =)

Comment: @HarryMattocks happy to help :) upvoting or marking as answered is highly appreciated

Comment: Sure, just check that incoming params[id] matches the current_user.id , if it matches than you do not beed to check the contact list

Answer (score 0):

```
  def is_contact
    user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if user = !@contacts
```

- the conditional is an assignment, to check equality you need to use `==
- also you need to check for presence in the list, the @contacts is going to be an array and that will never be equal to a member of the list
- You are also checking if the current_user is a contact, i think you need to look for the user that is being viewed

Probably should be something like this.  I would pull this is_contact checking out to a plain ruby object so that the concept is clear and external to your controller.

```
  def is_contact
    viewed_user = User.find(params[:id])
    viewed_user_is_contact = @contacts.any? {|contact| contact == user}
    if !viewed_user_is_contact
      #flash
```

Comment: @contacts will need to be set before that is ran, you could switch to `contacts` if that exists as a method on your controller now.